# Cocerning the Stack Diagram of this Function

Tags: python, recursion

```
def factorial(n):
    space = ' ' * (4*n)
    print (space, 'factorial', n)
    if n == 0 :
        print(space, 'returning 1')
        return 1
    else:
        recurse = factorial(n-1)
        result = n * recurse
        print(space, 'returning', result)
        return result

factorial(5)
```

and the result is,

```
                     factorial 5
                 factorial 4
             factorial 3
         factorial 2
     factorial 1
 factorial 0
 returning 1
     returning 1
         returning 2
             returning 6
                 returning 24
                     returning 120
```

Can't understand how we can proceed from "factorial 5" to "factorial 4" in next line.

Comment: Because of the first `print` statement, it's run unconditionally. So every time `factorial` is called, it prints the number that was passed as parameter.

Comment: Why or How(depends on the answer) print makes contional statement unconditional?

Comment: The program enters `factorial(5)` and prints `5`. It then takes the else branch, where it calls `factorial(5 - 1)`. The program then enters `factorial(5 - 1)`, where it prints `4`.

Comment: Print is outside any `if-else` branch, thus unconditional. You can try to debug it in the IDE that you're using, that will make it clearer.

Comment: Any special reason that print function is designed to be unconditional?